# Core Data remove object from to-many set not saving

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Hi I'm wondering if anyone could help me work out this Core Data issue.

I currently have two entites, `User` and `Product`. `User` has a to-many relationship to Product with no inverse relationship (as I don't want to know what `User`s have the `Product`, just what `Product`s a `User` has. Adding a product to a user works fine using the `addProductsObject` method in the sub-classes Xcode generates for me. The problem is when I try to remove the Product object from the `User` using the `removeProductsObject` it seems fine. The context is closed on `applicationDidEnterBackground` in the AppDelegate. However if I run my application in Xcode or kill the application and start it again, the relationship is still there like it wasn't deleted!

Objective-C, iOS 8 Simulator, Xcode 6.1.1

Anyone have any idea's?

**UPDATE: [Zip Project here if anyone would like to take a look!](http://www.filedropper.com/coredatatest)**

Image Link to the screenshot of relationships settings

[image]

Adding Product:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  [user addProductsObject:[self.products objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Removing Product:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [user removeProductsObject:[self.products objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

SQL Logs:

```
2015-02-18 22:41:17.635 Project[22802:1254740] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZDOB, t0.ZEMAIL, t0.ZFIRSTNAME, t0.ZLASTNAME, t0.ZLOCATION, t0.ZPASSWORD, t0.ZUSERNAME FROM ZUSER t0 WHERE  t0.ZUSERNAME = ? 
2015-02-18 22:41:17.635 Project[22802:1254740] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0003s
2015-02-18 22:41:17.635 Project[22802:1254740] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0005s for 1 rows.
2015-02-18 22:41:18.958 Project[22802:1254740] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK FROM ZPRODUCT t0 WHERE  t0.Z6PRODUCTS = ? 
2015-02-18 22:41:18.959 Project[22802:1254740] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0002s
2015-02-18 22:41:18.959 Project[22802:1254740] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0004s for 2 rows.
2015-02-18 22:41:18.959 Project[22802:1254740] CoreData: annotation: to-many relationship fault "products" for objectID 0xd000000000040000 <x-coredata://1C19A10A-BD0E-480B-B4A2-F6BBB26D9F74/User/p1> fulfilled from database.  Got 2 rows
2015-02-18 22:41:18.963 Project[22802:1254740] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZBARCODE, t0.ZCALORIES, t0.ZCARBOHYDRATES, t0.ZDESC, t0.ZFAT, t0.ZFIBRE, t0.ZNAME, t0.ZPROTEIN, t0.ZSALT, t0.Z6PRODUCTS FROM ZPRODUCT t0 WHERE  t0.Z_PK = ? 
2015-02-18 22:41:18.963 Project[22802:1254740] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0002s
2015-02-18 22:41:18.963 Project[22802:1254740] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0005s for 1 rows.
2015-02-18 22:41:18.964 Project[22802:1254740] CoreData: annotation: fault fulfilled from database for : 0xd0000000000c0002 <x-coredata://1C19A10A-BD0E-480B-B4A2-F6BBB26D9F74/Product/p3>
2015-02-18 22:41:18.965 Project[22802:1254740] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZBARCODE, t0.ZCALORIES, t0.ZCARBOHYDRATES, t0.ZDESC, t0.ZFAT, t0.ZFIBRE, t0.ZNAME, t0.ZPROTEIN, t0.ZSALT, t0.Z6PRODUCTS FROM ZPRODUCT t0 WHERE  t0.Z_PK = ? 
2015-02-18 22:41:18.965 Project[22802:1254740] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0002s
2015-02-18 22:41:18.965 Project[22802:1254740] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0003s for 1 rows.
2015-02-18 22:41:18.965 Project[22802:1254740] CoreData: annotation: fault fulfilled from database for : 0xd000000000100002 <x-coredata://1C19A10A-BD0E-480B-B4A2-F6BBB26D9F74/Product/p4>
```

Running `[managedObjectContext save:]` produces these log, quite strange why there isn't an update. Also why `Product` has a field called `products`. I opened the SQL database and in the entity `Product` there is an int called Products.

**ANSWERED**
The problem is I wrote some of my own method getters for the Core Data Object and that seemed to break the core data generation classes. Got rid of these and it all works fine! I've got the inverse in too now.

Comment: call `save:` on the managedobjectcontext that the `user` object is in immediately after removing the product object

Comment: Tried that, still the same.. Not too sure I've looked at the SQL Logs and these are in the thread.

Comment: the missing inverse relationship looks fishy. They are not as optional as one might think.

Comment: It probably is the missing inverse, but I want user to hold a collection products. So 1 user can hold multiple products.

Comment: If you add an inverse, it will still be possible for User to have many Products.  You will not need to use or update the inverse - CoreData will keep it in sync with the `products` relationship.

Comment: If you have answered your own question, it's considered good SO spirit to add you own answer to your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 5):

I guess, but I'm not sure, your model has not setup correctly.

Does it look like the following?

[image]

First of all, there is a `products` relationships (to many) where the delete rule has been set up as `cascade`. In addition, there is also the inverse (`user`) that has been set up to `nullify`. Graphically, they would be the following.

For `User` entity, the `products` relationship has been set up as

[image]

For `Product` entity, the `user` relationship has been set up as

[image]

About the optional flag, you need to decide based on your needs.

**Even if you don't want the inverse it's strongly suggested to set up it in order to let Core Data to maintain the graph consistency.**

Then, when you delete an object, you should run a `save` (passing also a `NSError`) in order to persist changes onto disk.

About the Sqlite store, mine is as follows:

ZUSER Table

[image]

ZPRODUCT Table

[image]

Comment: Yeah, it must be some issue with the relationship set up. 

It doesn't, there isn't an arrow from product to user. I would like User to hold a set of products but the products have no relationship back, thats why I did it without an inverse. 

I'm never actually deleting the object product, I'm just removing it from the NSSet in User. If that makes sense?

Comment: I've added a zip file, could you check that please see if you can see where it's going wrong?

Comment: +1. This is a highly detailed and well formed answer. It's a shame the question asker hasn't accepted it, but it should be. Inverse relationships are critical for To-Many relationships, even if you don't use them. If you don't have your inverse, you're going to get a lot of side-effects that you need a very, very good reason why you can't just have another property you don't use.

Comment: @Tim Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @LorenzoB ciao, I wonder why you favor CASCADE delete rule in your point 1?  What is your thinking there - thanks !

Comment: This answer saved me. This is exactly the reason why it was happening. It's a pity that it's not accepted as correct answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and adding inverse relatioship fixed it. Nothing else needed to be done.